# How to run api calls and execute their response parallel in c#?

Tags: c#, ruby, parallel-processing

I am from ruby background. I have a project need to be migrated to c#. It will make thousands of api service calls. In ruby I use Typhoeus Hydra to run the request parallel and execute the response parallel.

NOTE: each api call are separate no dependency between each call.

The template of ruby will be like this

```
#typhoeus gem used to make api call
QUEUE = Typhoeus::Hydra.new
[1..100].each do |val|
  request = Typhoeus::Request.new("http://api.com/?value=#{val}")
  request.on_complete do |response|
    # code to be executed after each call
  end
  QUEUE.queue(request)
end

#run the queue will run 100 api calls in parallel and execute complete block in parallel
QUEUE.run
```

I have little idea that i have to work with async and await (TPL) in c#. But I need some good examples which will be helpful.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shou should have look at the Parallel LINQ library (PLINQ).

You can do requests with like this:

```
Parallel.ForEach(Enumerable.Range(1, 100), (val) => 
{
  // make syncron api call 
  WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
  var result = webClient.DownloadString(string.Format("http://api.com/?value={0}", val);
  // work on the result
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion let me work on this angle also.

Answer (score 1):

Parallel processing is an option; however, it blocks threads unnecessarily. Since your operation is I/O-bound (hitting an HTTP API), asynchronous concurrency is a better option.

First, you'd define your "download and process" operation:

```
private static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
private static async Task DownloadAndProcessAsync(string value)
{
  var response = await client.GetStringAsync($"http://api.com/?value={value}");
  // Process response.
}
```

If you want to run them *all* concurrently, then a simple `Task.WhenAll` would suffice:

```
var source = Enumerable.Range(1, 100);
var tasks = source.Select(v => DownloadAndProcessAsync(v.ToString()));
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

For more information about `async`/`await`, see my [intro to `async` blog post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) (and the followup resources at the end of it).